# Перебор строк flask, обработка и обновление данных в таблице

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Есть таблица созданная через SQLALCHEMY, содержит в себе столбцы: id, address, ip, serialNumber, Status

В теории, должно перебирать все строки из таблицы и пинговать оборудования, брав IP из столбца ip,  если пинг есть - писать в столбец Status - 1. Если пинга нет - 2. Запутался в цикле, не знаю, как передать таблице в нужный столбец нужный текст( Прошу вашей помощи.

```
def ping_complexes(row_size):
    try:
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect('mangust.db')
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        print('Подключен к SQLite')
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * from mangustes"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        print("Чтение ", row_size, " строк")
        records = cursor.fetchmany(row_size)
        for row in records:
            ping(row[2])
            if ping(row[2]) in (None, False):
                cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mangustes VALUES (?);"""))) //???
            else:
                cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mangustes VALUES (?);"""))) //???
        cursor.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Ошибка при работае с SQLite", error)
    finally:
        if sqlite_connection:
            sqlite_connection.close()
            print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
ping_complexes(19)
```

**main.py целиком:**

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, request, redirect
from ping3 import ping
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///mangust.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Mangustes(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    ip = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    serialNumber = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    Status = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Mangustes %r>' % self.id


def ping_complexes(row_size):
    try:
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect('mangust.db')
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        print('Подключен к SQLite')
        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * from mangustes"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        print("Чтение ", row_size, " строк")
        records = cursor.fetchmany(row_size)
        for row in records:
            ping(row[2])
            if ping(row[2]) in (None, False):
                cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mangustes VALUES (?);""")
            else:
                cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO mangustes VALUES (?);""")
        cursor.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Ошибка при работае с SQLite", error)
    finally:
        if sqlite_connection:
            sqlite_connection.close()
            print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")



@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    mangustes = Mangustes.query.order_by(Mangustes.id).all()
    return render_template("index.html", mangustes=mangustes)

@app.route('/adding', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def adding():
    if request.method =="POST":
        ip = request.form['ip']
        address = request.form['address']
        serialNumber = request.form['serialNumber']
        complex = Mangustes(ip=ip, address=address, serialNumber=serialNumber)
        try:
            db.session.add(complex)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return "При добавлении комплекса произошла ошибка"
    else:
        return render_template("adding.html")





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменял ping_complexes, чтобы он использовал session.commit из flask_sqlalchemy. Добавил для теста заглушку на функцию ping(). Остальное не трогал.

```
def ping(smt):
    print("Now pinging {}".format(smt))
    result = bool(randint(0, 1))
    print("Result is {}".format(result))
    return result

def ping_complexes(row_size):
    try:
        records = Mangustes.query.limit(row_size).all()
        
        for record in records:
            if ping(record.ip) in (None, False):
                record.Status = 2
            else:
                record.Status = 1
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("???", e)
```

Comment: Это сработало, только пытаюсь установить таймер на повтор этой функции, а он говорит, что RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. Можно с Вами связаться в телеграмме? Осталось только это исправить  =) Спасибо!